# Preserving array state hook after routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to keep/preserve react `useState` hooks after routing to another page, now lets assume I have array called `sections` that saved in `useState` hook, inside the array I have 3 items

> Ads,
> Promote,
> Build

As I route to another rendering, the values of the the `useState` hook are resetting which includes the array.

**Related functions**

```
const [calculator, setCalculator] = useState({section: [], graphic: false}); //Sections array inside

   // Responsible to add item to the array, also promote and ads, just short version so you can understand
   function addPath(section){
        if(section === "build"){
            if(calculator.section.some(val => val === "build")){
                let filteredArray = calculator.section.filter(item => item !== 'build')
                setCalculator({section: filteredArray});
                $('.build').removeClass('active');
            }
            else{
                var joined = calculator.section.concat('build');
                setCalculator({ section: joined })
                $('.build').addClass('active');
            }
        }
    }

//Route from /start to /values
const Continue = () =>{
    history.push("/values");
    history.go(0);
}

// Check if the item exist in the array after routing the page
function checkArray(val) {
    return calculator.section.some(item => item === val);
}
```

**JSX**

```
 <Route path="/start">
     <p className="secondary">
        בחר מסלול רלוונטי (ניתן לבחור יותר מאחד)
     </p>
     <Row className="margTop">
           <Col lg="4"><img id="firstSelectors" className="build" onClick={() => addPath('build')} src={Code} alt="בניית אתרים" /></Col>
           <Col lg="4"><img id="firstSelectors" className="promote" onClick={() => addPath('promote')}  src={Promotion} alt="קידום אתרים" /></Col>
           <Col lg="4"><img id="firstSelectors" className="ad" onClick={() => addPath('ad')}  src={Advertise} alt="שיווק דיגטלי" /></Col>
       </Row>
       <button onClick={Continue}>המשך</button>
  </Route>
  <Route path="/values">
        {checkArray('ad') ? 'yes' : 'no'}
  </Route>
```

How can I preserve `useState` hook after routing to another page? right now it's resetting (I have debugged calculator value to check that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your use-case I would create a new hook that reads from localStorage on mount and persists changes to localStorage.

The [useLocalStorage](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/) hook from useHooks is a good fit here